# Авторизация в Instagram без использования API

Tags: delphi, instagram

Пишу код на Delphi, используя библиотеки httpsend и ssl_openssl.
Все бы хорошо, но не могу залогиниться на сайте инстаграма. Выдает ошибку:

> HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request.

Код следующий.

```
procedure TForm1.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var HTTP:THTTPSend;
    HTML:TStringList;
    Data:TStringStream;
begin
  HTTP:=THTTPSend.Create;
  HTML:=TStringList.Create;
  HTTP.HTTPMethod('GET','https://www.instagram.com');
  token:=StringReplace(HTTP.Cookies[0], 'csrftoken=','',[rfReplaceAll]);
  //HTTP.Clear;
  Data:=TStringStream.Create('username=loginnnn&password=passsssss');
  HTTP.Document.LoadFromStream(Data); 
  HTTP.UserAgent:='User-Agent : Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0';
  HTTP.Headers.Add('X-CSRFToken : ' + token);
  HTTP.Headers.Add('X-Instagram-AJAX : 1');
  HTTP.Headers.Add('X-Requested-With : XMLHttpRequest');
  HTTP.Headers.Add('Referer : https://www.instagram.com/');
  HTTP.MimeType:='application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8';

  HTTP.HTTPMethod('POST','https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/ajax');
  mmo1.Text:=HTTP.Headers.Text;
  HTTP.Clear;

  HTTP.Headers.Add('X-CSRFToken : ' + token);
  HTTP.HTTPMethod('POST','https://www.instagram.com/web/likes/116374461280/like/');
  HTTP.Clear;
  ShowMessage(HTTP.Headers.Text);
  HTTP.Clear;
end;
```

Comment: Не можете залогинится, а что не получается, что получаете в ответ, код ошибки какой-то есть? Добавьте подробностей.

Comment: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

Comment: Добавьте это в вопрос

Comment: А вы разве по `https` ходите? Нужно указать протокол явно: `HTTP.HTTPMethod('POST','https://www.instagram.com/web/likes/116374461280/like/');`. Соответственно, рядом с вашим `exe` должны лежать либы для поддержки `ssl`.

Comment: Используеться HTTPS. При первом создании темы мне не дали возможность дописать ссылки)) потому немного сократил

Comment: получилось решить проблему?

Comment: Правильные хедеры помогли